# Repeat animation when button is press

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, animation

I have an attack animation that I want to repeat animation whenever the button for attack is clicking all I can come up is one show of animation only,when the button is press again the animation won't repeat again
here is my animation code

```
imgAttack = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgAttack);
        imgAttack.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.attack_anim);
        attackanimation=(AnimationDrawable)imgAttack.getBackground();

btnAtk.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
               press=+1;
                MaxHealth-=100;

                swordAtk.start();

               attackanimation.start();




                health.setProgress(MaxHealth);
                if(MaxHealth==0) {


                    health.setProgress(0);
                    Gold=Gold+1;
                    txtGold.setText("Gold:"+Gold);
                    SharedPreferences prefs = RpgActivity.this.getSharedPreferences(getString( R.string.PREF_FILE),MODE_PRIVATE);
                    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
                    editor.putInt(getString(R.string.SDR),Gold);
                    editor.apply();
                }
            }
        });
```

> here is my xml for attack_anim.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<animation-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    >
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/attak0001" android:duration="100" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/attak0002" android:duration="100" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/attak0003" android:duration="100" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/attak0004" android:duration="100" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/attak0005" android:duration="100" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/attak0006" android:duration="100" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/attak0007" android:duration="100" />

</animation-list>
```

Comment: What is your requirement can you specify clearly. Because as per the android default, the animation drawable must continue running.

Comment: i need to reset animation and play it again when the attack button is press

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this before `attackAnimation.start()`

```
attackAnimation.stop();
attackAnimation.selectDrawable(0);
```

and after that write `attackAnimation.start()`.

Comment: its playing unlimited i only want to play it once the button is click then play it once only again when the button is click again

Comment: i found it sir i add android:oneshot="true " int the xml file

Comment: Yes , you are right. And don't call me as Sir. Just call as friend.